# What trait prevents arguments from including pointers to heap-allocated data?

Tags: rust, traits, heap-memory

I am writing code that only works if the argument passed in doesn't include any pointers. The following is ok:

```rust
let x: u32 = 1;
foo(&x)

struct MyStruct {
  a: u32,
  b: u32,
}

let x = MyStruct {a: 1, b:2};
foo(&x)
```

The following is not ok:

```rust
let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
foo(&x)

let x = Box::new(1);
foo(&x)
```

What type should I give to the first argument of `foo` such that the bad examples are rejected?

```rust
fn foo<T>(x: T) where T: /* WHAT? */ {
  ....
}
```

Comment: ...but why is including pointers not okay?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Aplet123 Because I'm going to store the value/structure in shared memory between two processes - like storing it in a byte slice. Using a pointer inside of this structure will lead to a segfault when I try to read the value.

Comment: @xixixao You _could_ define your own empty trait `trait PlainData {}` and while cumbersome implement it for all types. You might be able to use it in conjunction with [`type_name()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/fn.type_name.html) and check for the presence of `&` or `*` and panic at runtime. However the output of `type_name()` is not guaranteed. With all that said, you should probably use another way of sharing data between processes, such as with sockets and/or serializing using [`serde`](https://crates.io/crates/serde)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're searching for is `Sync`, or respectively `Send`. Citing the [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html):

> - A type is Send if it is safe to send it to another thread.
> - A type is Sync if it is safe to share between threads (&T is Send).

> Almost all primitives are Send and Sync, and as a consequence pretty much all types you'll ever interact with are Send and Sync.
> Major exceptions include:
>
> - raw pointers are neither Send nor Sync (because they have no safety guards).
> - UnsafeCell isn't Sync (and therefore Cell and RefCell aren't).
> - Rc isn't Send or Sync (because the refcount is shared and unsynchronized).

It doesn't do *exactly* what the title of the question asks for, but judging from the comments to your question it might perhaps do what you want, which seems to be making sure that a type is save to share between threads.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Send/Sync work for threads in one process because those threads can share any memory allocated to the process. In my case I can only share the single shared contiguous memory array.